# FooTable breakpoints?

Tags: jquery-plugins, footable

From the documentation on the FooTable website, I had the impression that table 'breaking' depended on screen resolution (or browser window width). Thus, the browser width.

But in practice, it seems to 'break' tables depending on the width of the container element they're in, eg. a DIV element.

How are these breakpoints supposed to work?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, I did not read the docs well enough.

They state: "FooTable works with the concepts of "breakpoints", which are different table widths we care about."

Thus, breaking points are about table width, not window or screen width.

Duh...

Comment: So is it not possible to use custom breakpoints? They've never worked for me and thousands of others - it just completely ignores them and always defaults to "tablet" and "phone" . The "tiny" in their examples never works. Maddening!